# Why in MySQL 5.6, auto increment on int field skip '2147483646'?

Tags: mysql

When I was testing the boundary for int auto-incrementing primary key following is observed in MySQL 5.6

```
   drop table if exists f1;
   create table f1 (
        i int(11)  not null auto_increment,
        primary key (`i`)
   )ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2147483640 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

   insert into f1 values (); -- execute this for 8 times

   select * from f1;

+------------+
| i          |
+------------+
| 2147483640 |
| 2147483641 |
| 2147483642 |
| 2147483643 |
| 2147483644 |
| 2147483645 |
| 2147483647 |
+------------+
```

entry for 2147483646 is missed. Can anyone explain why there is this behavior?

without autoincrement, 2147483646 can be populated manually

```
drop table if exists f1;
create table f1 (
  i int(11)  not null ,
 primary key (`i`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2147483640 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into f1 values (2147483644),(2147483645),(2147483646),(2147483647);

select * from f1;

+------------+
| i          |
+------------+
| 2147483644 |
| 2147483645 |
| 2147483646 |
| 2147483647 |
+------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's interesting. I have read the forum. I think it's expected behavior of MySQL.

FYI:

- [Bug #75941   auto_increment value jumps from the max row value - 2 to max](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75941)

> [18 Feb 2015 12:54] Peter Laursen I think you should read this
>   carefully
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_m...
>
> There have been lots of similar reports here before (I posted such
>   myself 4-5 years ago). There is no guarantee that there will not be
>   'holes' in autoincrement enumeration. This is not what
>   'auto_increment' means. It "increments", but is not guaranteed to
>   always "increment by one".
>
> But if you set 'innodb_autoinc_lock_mode' to "0" it will rarely happen
>   - if at all - that such 'holes' occur.
>
> -- Peter
>   -- not a MySQL/Oracle person.